# Pause button in SpriteKit takes several taps to resume the game

Tags: sprite-kit, swift3

I have read several questions/answers posted about pausing a scene in SpriteKit but none solve the issue I’m having.

I have a pause button on my game scene. The Z position is much higher than any other SKSpriteNode in the scene. The first problem is that sometimes it takes 2 or 3 taps to pause the scene but the MAIN problem is that to resume the game, sometimes it works as it should with just one tap but some other times, tapping on it advances 2 - 3 frames and I have to tap sometimes even 5 times for the game to fully resume.

Below is the code I’m using for my pause button and it is inside my touchesMoved function using Swift 3. Could you guys offer any suggestions to improve this code and fix this glitch? Thanks for your help.

```
        let nodeUserTapped = atPoint(pointOfTouch)

        if nodeUserTapped.name == "PauseButton" {

            if (self.isPaused == true) {
                self.isPaused = false
                physicsWorld.speed = 1
            } else {
                self.isPaused = true
                physicsWorld.speed = 0
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you should use `touchesBegan` simply to animate the button with a "pressed button" texture, then put your code in `touchesEnded` to be sure to run it when the user release the finger inside the button. The code you've written in `touchesMoved` is run only when the finger slide at least a little bit on the screen.